# Using object literal on web editor for writing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, codemirror, object-literal, code-editor

Is there any possibility to configure web code editors like CodeMirror, Ace, or Brace, or any other editor so that I can write not only using JSON format but also object literal? What I am going to achieve is:

1. Being able to write strings with single quotes
2. Defining object keys with or without quotation marks
   Basically, the possibility of editing JSON while allowing to use of some JS features.

Comment: I mean, if you're not writing JSON, but just JavaScript, you want to be in JavaScript mode, not JSON mode.

Comment: What's the use case? If it's a JSON file, it has to conform to the JSON limitations.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think I made the title of this question a bit misleading. What I want neither Javascript nor JSON mode. It's more of a hybrid mode in which I can use SOME of the JS features. If It's just Javascript mode,  I will get syntax errors.

Comment: It sounds like you want a custom language or document format. You would need to find an editor that supported those kinds of things and provide the format/rules. I don't know of any. Your title is still mislead, BTW, because it sounds to me like the end document is not JSON, but something else.

Comment: @Barmar It's not a JSON file. It's a page where the configuration values can be edited. Right now it supports only JSON format. I would like to add more flexibility to it.